# What is the behaviour of a send queue for an unconnected UNIX datagram sockets in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I want to clarify my understanding of send queues for the unix datagram sockets.

Let us have two non-blocking unconnected unix datagram sockets CLIENT and SERVER (bound to the same filenames).

1. Are there RX,TX queues for each socket or just RX queues?
2. If I call `sendto(CLIENT,data,SERVER)`, in which queue of which socket is data stored exactly?
3. If the SERVER socket is ignored and its RX queue becomes full, `sendto` will fail. But will the CLIENT still be writeable by `POLLOUT`?
4. What happens to another `sendto` to some other SERVER2 (that has empty RX queue), will it be sent immediately or will it be blocked by unsent messages enqueued in CLIENT's TX queue destined to SERVER?

I am mainly interested in Linux implementation which is supposed to be ordered and reliable.